# Returning warning messages in R and VS Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

When running R code from VS Code that produces warnings, the warning messages generated earlier are put out for each evaluated expression that is fed into the interpreter, even if the expression would normally not produce a warning.

The warning messages are always preceeded by the first line in the given warning message output below:

```
warning messages from top-level task callback 'vsc.workspace'
Warning messages:
1: In grep(pattern, values, value = TRUE) :
  input string 2 is invalid in this locale
2: In grep(pattern, values, value = TRUE) :
  input string 3 is invalid in this locale
```

Can such recurring warning messages be turned off somehow? What is the vsc.workspace that seemingly generates the warnings every time?

Restarting the R session with the following code seems to solve the problem:

```
assign('.Last',  function() {system('R')}, envir = globalenv())
quit(save = 'no')
```

However, restarting the session each time when a warning is generated seems quite tedious